# Swift - HTTP digest auth

Tags: ios, swift, http, request, alamofire

I am currently in the process of reverse engineering a home automation API. I want to manage all settings with my own app - because there is really no current home automation app of the company.

Anyway - I already managed the authentication with my **SmartHome device**. To not make it too complicated: I need **http digest authentication** for final communication.
I have already been able to connect to my device through the command line with curl - unfortunately this doesn't work in Swift as planned.

```
curl -X POST -d '{"key": "value"}' https://192.168.0.0:1/action -k -s --digest --user username:password
```

Translated to Swift:

(1) Using Alamofire

```
import Alamofire
let data: [String: any] = ["key": "value"]
let request = Alamofire.request("https://192.168.0.0:1/action", method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: data);
request.authenticate(user: "username", password: "password")
request.responseJSON { response in
    // leads to error because of invalid self signed certificate of the smart home device ("https:")
}
```

Note to Alamofire: I guess using an external libary such as AF does not make much sense in this case - there are some unresolved issues that wont let such code as above work. (Self signed ceritficates makes problems, using custom manager instances overriding internal stuff leads also to problems) - I've already spent hours believe me.

(2) Using not Alamofire :)

```
extension ViewController: URLSessionDelegate {
    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        let urlCredential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, urlCredential)
    }
}



let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted)
    request.httpBody = jsonData;
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            return
        }
        let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
        // success
        }
    }
    task.resume()
} catch { }
```

The code above seems to work fine - the problem is that I've not implemented the digest authentication yet - because I do not find any method how to do this.

It would be super helpful if somebody to get some tips how generate the Auth header based on username and password

**Edit**

Curl uses this **Authorization** header:

```
> Digest username="username", 
realm="XTV", 
nonce="MTU5MDcNc2UxNjQ3OTo1YzMwYjc3YjIxMzAAAGQ5Nzg2NzUzMmRkZGU1ZVVlYw==", 
uri="/action", 
cnonce="MTExOTZlZmI1MjBlYWU0MTIzMDBmNDE0YTkWzJl1MDk=", 
nc=00000001, 
qop=auth, 
response="2ba89269645e2aa24ac6f117d85e190c", 
algorithm="MD5"
```

**Is there the possibility to generate this header in Swift?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digest authentication is supported automatically by `URLSession` and Alamofire through `URLCredential` (which is what `authenticate()` uses in Alamofire) when the server properly returns the `WWW-Authenticate` header with the proper digest settings.

You can generate the header manually, though I wouldn't recommend it due to the complexity of the digest process. I've found the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) to be thorough enough to implement the standard manually.

Comment: If you're using `URLSession` directly, you either need to implement the appropriate delegate method `urlSession(_:didReceive:completionHandler:)` or add the credential directly to your `URLCredentialStorage`.